# Updating Object Breaks View - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**UPDATED**

This was a problem that resulted from using the [Angular UI Grid](https://github.com/s-yadav/angulargrid) // end update

I'm trying to update changes made to an array of objects after a PUT is made to update a single object.

I've tried various solutions which seem to work but end up breaking the view. The problem may be that I am using a modal so I'm defining $scope differently on the .html pages.

When loading the page I'm getting all the user's Looks and adding them to:

```
$scope.userLooks = data;
```

When user clicks on edit button it shows the modal with fields populated to `$scope.editLook`

```
$scope.editLook = function(look) {
  looksAPI.getUpdateLook(look)
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.editLook = data.data;
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('failed to get look ', err);
    });
}
```

I'm able to save the data so it updates on backend but am having trouble updating this new object to my original array of objects

```
$scope.saveLook = function() {
  var look = $scope.editLook;

  looksAPI.updateLook(look)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      alertSuccess.show();
    }, function(err) {
      alertFail.show();
    });
}
```

I've tried different things like this code below which is supposed to iterate over the original objects to see if any have changed and then update accordingly.

```
      .then(function(data) {
      angular.forEach($scope.userLooks, function(u, i) {
        if (u._id === look._id) {
          $scope.userLooks[i] = data;
        }
      })
```

Also tried passing a GET request after the PUT and the results are the same broken view.

This is my modal view:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text"
              class="form-control title-input"
              placeholder="{{ editLook.title }}"
              ng-model="editLook.title" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row listing-description-row">
    <label for="description"
              class="col-xs-12">Description</label>
      <textarea type="text"
              class="form-control description-textarea"
              placeholder="{{ editLook.description }}"
              ng-model="editLook.description"
              rows="3" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

And mylook view which is using Angular Grid.

```
<ul class="dynamic-grid angular-grid"
          angular-grid="looks"
          grid-width="300"
          gutter-size="10"
          angular-grid-id="gallery"
          refresh-on-img-load="true" >
      <li data-ng-repeat="look in userLooks"
          class="grid"
          ng-cloak>
        <a ui-sref="look ({ lookId: look._id })"
            class="lookLink">
          <img ng-src="{{ look.image }}"
                  class="grid-img"
                  data-actual-width="{{ look.actualWidth }}"
                  data-actual-height="{{ look.actualHeight }}" />
          <div class="look-description-trim">
            {{ look.description.substr(0,100) }}
          </div>

          <div class="titleClass">
            {{ look.title }}
          </div>
        </a></li></ul>
```

Comment: what does "Breaks View" mean? and how can we troubleshoot an issue with a view when you haven't provided any HTML?

Comment: I lose the navigation menu, scroll bar disappears, the objects become out of alignment and the Look being changed disappears.  I've added my html for the views.

Comment: Did you close the <ul> tag ?

Comment: Yes, the page loads fine on entry.  Its only after trying to update the userLooks scope object with updated data that things break.